Enforcing type safety between concrete subclasses of an abstract base class
I'm facing a type safety issue in my Python project involving an abstract base class (AbstractClass) and its concrete subclasses (ConcreteClassA and ConcreteClassB). Each concrete class implements abstract methods from AbstractClass, but I'm struggling to enforce type safety between the two concrete classes.
Here's a simplified version of my code structure:
class AbstractClass(ABC):
    class rational:
        pass

    @dataclass
    class Frac(rational):
        value1: int
        value2: int

    @dataclass
    class Whole(rational):
        value: int

    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def foo(cls, x: int, y: int) -> rational:
        pass

    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def boo(cls, r: rational) -> str:
        pass


class ConcreteClassA(AbstractClass):
    @classmethod
    def foo(cls, x: int, y: int) -> AbstractClass.rational:
        ...

    @classmethod
    def boo(cls, r: AbstractClass.rational) -> str:
        ...

    @staticmethod
    def __reduce(r: AbstractClass.rational) -> AbstractClass.Whole | AbstractClass.Frac:
        match r:
            case Rational1.Whole(_):
                return r
            case Rational1.Frac(x, y):
                if x == 0:
                    return AbstractClass.Whole(0)
                else:
                    d = Rational1.foo(abs(x), y)
                    if d == y:
                        return AbstractClass.Whole(x // d)
                    else:
                        return AbstractClass.Frac(x // d, y // d)
            case _:
                raise Exception("ERRR")


class ConcreteClassB(AbstractClass):
    @classmethod
    def foo(cls, x: int, y: int) -> AbstractClass.rational:
        ...

    @classmethod
    def boo(cls, r: AbstractClass.rational) -> str:
        ...

    @staticmethod
    def __reduce(r: AbstractClass.rational) -> AbstractClass.Whole | AbstractClass.Frac:
        match r:
            case Rational1.Whole(_):
                return r
            case Rational1.Frac(x, y):
                if x == 0:
                    return AbstractClass.Whole(0)
                else:
                    d = Rational1.foo(abs(x), y)
                    if d == y:
                        return AbstractClass.Whole(x // d)
                    else:
                        return AbstractClass.Frac(x // d, y // d)
            case _:
                raise Exception("ERRR")


a = ConcreteClassA.boo(ConcreteClassB.foo(9, -6))
b = ConcreteClassB.boo(ConcreteClassA.foo(9, -6))


EDIT: As you can see there are static methods and other methods that call each other, and I don't think the implementation will allow Self to be present in the abstract class.
Despite the structure, there's no enforcement of type safety between ConcreteClassA and ConcreteClassB. For example, calls like ConcreteClassA.boo with ConcreteClassB.foo arguments don't lead to any error, which is undesirable.
I'm using Pyright for type checking. How can I modify my code to ensure that errors are created when passing data between ConcreteClassA and ConcreteClassB? Please note that I prefer not to add generics, type aliases, or other constructs directly into the main class.
And also @dataclass implementation inside the AbstractClass, just go with it.

What does the last sentence (with @dataclass) mean?

Why should ConcreteClassA.boo(ConcreteClassB.foo(9, -6)) lead to an error? ConcreteClassB.foo returns a AbstractClass.rational and ConcreteClassA accepts a AbstractClass.rational, so everything is fine.

@mkrieger1 There was more to it, but this was the easiest way I could implement it

I would like to receive an error if subclasses "data types" are mixed, even tho primitive types were given. A method accepts a primitive type does it thing and whatever returns should not be usable for the other subclass. Something around the idea of two different modules with the same type.

Maybe methods should have AbstractClass.rational removed, and use other type or something similar... idk. What type should those methods have to be able to use rational inside the main class? I would mostly prefer not to give a TypeAlias or change the structure of main class, just to somehow modify the subclasses types and maybe syntax, idk. I'm new to OOP and python.

You really must provide a [mcve]. Don't make us guess your imports, and there are other undefined things here as well.

In any case, you posted a similar question before, but this version doesn't really clarify anything. You say "Despite the structure, there's no enforcement of type safety between ConcreteClassA and ConcreteClassB. For example, calls like ConcreteClassA.boo with ConcreteClassB.foo arguments don't lead to any error, which is undesirable." doesn't make any sense. You never call ConcreteClassA.boo with  ConcereteClassB.foo, you call it *with the result of calling ConcreteClassB.foo(...). Can you explain, precisely, why a = ConcreteClassA.boo(ConcreteClassB.foo(9, -6)) should error?

This is totally unclear: "I would like to receive an error if subclasses "data types" are mixed, even tho primitive types were given. A method accepts a primitive type does it thing and whatever returns should not be usable for the other subclass. Something around the idea of two different modules with the same type." Python doesn't have primitive types. But it sounds like you want to ConcreteClassA.boo to only accept the results of calling other methods on ConcereteClassA. This isn't "type safety".

What you are asking defeats the whole purpose of inheritance. If you want that, then simply define your types without any inheritance relationships. Why do you do that if you don't actually want any of that?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@juanpa.arrivillaga, the core elements I'm focusing on are the classmethods and staticmethods, while the rest is just the internal function logic. Mark's approach, as described in his answer, where he defined the instances of an and b in his code, is what I'm aiming for. However, I'm struggling to implement Self in the context of how these concrete classes are created. On the other hand when I said primitive type I was referring to "objects" like int, etc. So what do you mean that defeats the whole purpose of inheritance? (I'm new to OOP)

Why do you put "objets" in scare quotes. 1 is an object, just as much as {"a":1}' is an object, just as much as AbstractClass.Whole(0) is an object. But this is all besides the point. What you are saying here doesn't make any sense, "Mark's approach ... where he defined the instances of a an b in his code" that isn 't what Marks code does differently from your code. Mark's code (incorrectly) uses Self as the return type. But clearly, you want the return type to be some type of AbstractClass.rational, not Self.

But again, the type you seem to be trying to get at is something like "only accept objects returned by methods of this same class" but that isn't a type. One way you could do that is simply by defining a type just to be returned from that method, and make the other methods in that class accept only that type. But you are using inheritance. The whole point of inheritance is to say "this type can serve as the same type as the type I am inheriting from". That's what I mean by inheritance serving the opposite purpose of what you seem to want (again, it's not totally clear)\

So, Self is just used to signify an instance of the class it is being used on. So in the context of, say, ConcreteClassB.boo, where the parameter r is annotataed with Self, that means that parameter is expecting **an instance of ConcreteClassB`. Which is clearly not what you want

In your case, you've annotated the type as AbastractClass.rational, so that means that it will accept anything that inherits from AbstractClass.rational. That's the whole point of using inheritances and abstract base classes. It seems to be the opposite of what you are actually trying to achieve.

Yes, you are right. So even if both subclasses are exactly the same, from implementation to types, I should get an error if a method from a class returns perfect valid answer to another method of another class.

So abstract methods should get a Generic type of some sort? There is no way around that?

I don't know what this means: "So even if both subclasses are exactly the same, from implementation to types, I should get an error if a method from a class returns perfect valid answer to another method of another class". It doesn't sound correct. Did you mean "I shouldn't get an error"?

I don't think generics are an answer to what you need. Again, you seem to want to restrict the parameter to only accept an object based on what method returns it. That isn't what generics are for (nothing is really for that, that isn't something supported by the type system, or any type system I'm familiar with -- which isn't that many). One way would be to defined types that are only used by the methods in your class, and other methods in that class would only accept that type. It could potentially inherit from the rational bas class, but you would need to use the subclass in the annotation

"So even if both subclasses are exactly the same, from implementation to types, I should get an error if a method from a class returns perfect valid answer to another method of another class" - I tried to say In Python, even if subclasses have identical implementations and return types, maybe there's no built-in mechanism to enforce compatibility between methods from different subclasses. This means a method call might work as expected, but there's no guarantee of consistent behavior across subclasses due to potential differences in implementation details.

So that's why maybe I find it hard to make them incompatible. idk ....

Yes, 100%. I won't delete the question, I'll leave it as it is maybe someday some1 will answer it :)

Btw should I change the title?

I believe you're looking for Self. Self is used to mean an instance of the current class - see below:
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Self


class AbstractClass(ABC):
    class rational:
        pass

    @dataclass
    class Frac(rational):
        value1: int
        value2: int

    @dataclass
    class Whole(rational):
        value: int

    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def foo(cls, x: int, y: int) -> Self:
        pass

    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def boo(cls, r: Self) -> str:
        pass


class ConcreteClassA(AbstractClass):
    @classmethod
    def foo(cls, x: int, y: int) -> Self:
        ...

    @classmethod
    def boo(cls, r: Self) -> str:
        ...


class ConcreteClassB(AbstractClass):
    @classmethod
    def foo(cls, x: int, y: int) -> Self:
        ...

    @classmethod
    def boo(cls, r: Self) -> str:
        ...
    

a = ConcreteClassA.boo(ConcreteClassB.foo(9, -6)) # error
b = ConcreteClassB.boo(ConcreteClassA.foo(9, -6)) # error
a = ConcreteClassA.boo(ConcreteClassA.foo(9, -6)) # no error
b = ConcreteClassB.boo(ConcreteClassB.foo(9, -6)) # no error


Yes, this is the main goal, unfortunately the implementation cannot allow Self for a return type. Maybe I don't understand something. I'm going to answer myself and add more code.

I've just edited the current question because I find it challenging to follow the comment thread for future reference.

but foo doesn't return Self

That's strange - Self as a return type is quite often used to indicate when a class method makes an instance of the class it's contained within (see here: https://typing.readthedocs.io/en/latest/spec/generics.html#use-in-classmethod-signatures). Are you using python 3.11 or 3.12?
